# Can't create a new open graph achievement 

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, achievements

I keep getting the error:

"The given selector string \"game:points\" is invalid for Ent with ID 10150679224277659"

when trying to create a new achievement
(using https://graph.facebook.com/myappid/achievements/?method=post&access_token=...achievement=newurl)

this new achievement is totally different and has a different URL so why it keeps telling me about the other ID (10150679224277659) in this error?

Any ideas?

Comment: There are many reasons to fail while registering an achievement in FB opengraph. Are you using FB's default achievement (or) Are you defining your own achievement action/object?
The URL to your achievement should be different in case if its default achievement.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you're trying to share must be already detected as a different object; are you using an og:url tag on the avchievement URLs which point to another page?

According to http://graph.facebook.com/10150679224277659 that's of type 'game'

THE URL of that object (`http://apps.facebook.com/rummikubilan/themes/rummikub/achievement/win.aspx?title=3+parrots+in+a+row&description=Ilan+earned+3+parrots+in+Rummikubs+Jungle+World+and+won+25+Joker+credits\u002521\u002521+Super+cool\u002521&amount=25`) doesn't look right - it seems to have a description there which wouldn't make sense for an achievement because there's a name hardcoded into it.

Putting that URL through the debugger doesn't work either, When i go there via HTTPS it fails because you've not configured the secure URL, and in HTTP mode it fails with a 404 error:
[image: 404 image]

You should probably start with a different URL path for the achievements and make sure the meta tags are correct and resolvable, and that the og:url tags don't redirect elsewhere; the Achievement docs have some good examples: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/achievements/

Comment: That's is the problem. I'm trying to create a new achievement - the achievement URL is: http://apps.facebook.com/rummikubilan/themes/rummikub/OpenGraph/first_place_badge.aspx?title=title&description=description - it's different from the previous URL. so that's why I can't understand why it give's me an error with the other URL..